# How to set Label data value field and text value field on asp.net web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding, label

I have this code behind on my project:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (AuthenticateService.LoggedUser == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
            return;
        }

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            RefreshItems();
        }
    }

    private void RefreshItems()
    {
        GridViewTasks.DataSource = taskRepo.GetAll();
        GridViewTasks.DataBind();
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)GridViewTasks.FooterRow.FindControl("ddList");
        ddl.DataSource = userRepo.GetAll();
        ddl.DataValueField = "UserId";
        ddl.DataTextField = "UserName";

    }
```

I want to add some more functionality to this **RefreshItems**() method.

I have GridView where i show my data from my database.

I have **DropDownList** and i set its **DataValueField** and **DataTextField** to my **UserId** and **UserName** values, after i got them from my data base. This **DropDownList** appear when i click add new tasks

I also have **columns** named **CreatedBy** and **AssignedTo** with labels in GridView and i want to show them on GridView just like my DropDownList - Label value should be UserId value and Label text should be UserName.

and this is what it look like

http://prikachi.com/images.php?images/624/7885624d.jpg

How can i set labels values and text properly to show them with usernames on GridView ?

Here is my page code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CreatedBy" SortExpression="CreatedBy">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lbCreatedBy" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CreatedBy") %'>
```

Comment: you have to get the corresponding text names while fetching the result set from DB For eg: CreatedByName, AssignedtoName else you can implement data row bound event where in you can make a DB call to get the name and set it on Label. But i personally prefer first way.